# How to get object from Button click on listview row

Tags: listview, android-listview, xamarin.android, listviewitem

I'm trying to store/get the object when I click on a Button on a row on a ListView.

So, this is my code for clicking a ListView row which works as intended

```
            //Listview
            ListView mainListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstViewMain);

            //Custom adapter (taking a list "allComponents")
            ComponentListViewAdapter adapter = new ComponentListViewAdapter(this, allComponents);
            mainListView.Adapter = adapter;

            //Listview item/row click
            mainListView.ItemClick += MainListView_ItemClick;
```

```
        //Function to show the component's notes
        private void MainListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the component tapped
            var component = allComponents[(int)e.Id];

            //Display message that the component was tapped
            Toast.MakeText(this, component.Name.ToString() + " Tapped", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            // Declare the activity as intent
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(View_NotesActivity));

            //Transfer the component's notes to the notes screen for display
            intent.PutExtra("component_notes", component.Notes);

            //Start the activity of intent
            StartActivity(intent);
         }
```

Though when I implement the same logic for when tapping on a button on a ListView row

```
            //Edit button
            ImageButton btnEditComponent = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imgBtnEditComponent);
            btnEditComponent.Click += BtnEditComponent_Click;
```

```
        private void BtnEditComponent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

I get the error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

I managed to implement the edit button in the custom ListView adapter class but I don't know how to access "AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e" like in the MainListView_ItemClick function in order to store the object/component in a variable, again like in the MainListView_ItemClick function as follows:

```
        //Function to show the component's notes
        private void MainListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the component tapped
            var component = allComponents[(int)e.Id];
```

These are two attempts at implementing the Edit button (the button on the ListView) in the custom ListView adapter class, nether ways I know how to access/store the component that the Edit Button is on for a given row.

```
            //Edit component button
            editComponent = row.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imgBtnEditComponent);
            editComponent.Click += EditComponent_Click;
```

Attempt 1:

```
        private void EditComponent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the component tapped
            //This does not work like it does with the ListView row tap function.
            //var component = allComponents[(int)e.Id];

            Toast.MakeText(mContext, e.ToString() + " Edited", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            //Retuns "System.EventArgs Edited"

            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Attempt 2:

```
            //Set on click listener for the Edit component Button
            editComponent.SetOnClickListener(this);
```

```
        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            switch (v.Id)
            {
                case Resource.Id.imgBtnEditComponent:

                 //How can I grab the component when the only argument is a View?

                 break;
         }
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the `GetView()` method of your adapter :

```
//Edit component button
editComponent = row.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imgBtnEditComponent);
editComponent.Tag = position;
//Set on click listener for the Edit component Button
editComponent.SetOnClickListener(this);
```

then (if allComponents is your data source)

```
public void OnClick(View v)
    {
      int position = （int）v.Tag；
      var component = allComponents[position];
    }
```